# Upload image using paperclip, fog and rackspace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, fog, rackspace

I need to upload an logo image to rackspace using fog & paperclip.

```
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options.update({
  :path => "images/:class/:id/:attachment/:style/img_:fingerprint",
  :storage => :fog,
  :fog_credentials => {
  :provider           => 'Rackspace',
  :rackspace_username => 'blablabla',
  :rackspace_api_key  => 'blablabla',
  :persistent => false
},
:fog_directory => 'blablabla',
:fog_public => true,
:fog_host => 'http://blablabla.rackcdn.com'
})
```

I have this settings in config/initializers/paperclip_defaults.rb

But how to initialize the logo to catch those settings. Please help me i was in a confusion here.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to initialize the logo to "catch" those settings

Let me explain how it works:

> `Paperclip` simply creates an entry into your db, and stores your file on Rackspace. Accessing the file, with `paperclip` will simply be a case of ensuring `paperclip` is able to load the RackSpace URL correctly

I would do this:

```
#config/application.rb
config.paperclip_defaults = {
    styles: { :medium => "x500", :thumb => "x200" },
    default_url: "placeholder.png"
}

#config/environments/production.rb
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options.merge!({
     :path => "images/:class/:id/:attachment/:style/img_:fingerprint",
     :storage => :fog,
     :fog_credentials => {
        :provider           => 'Rackspace',
        :rackspace_username => 'blablabla',
        :rackspace_api_key  => 'blablabla',
        :persistent => false
     },
     :fog_directory => 'blablabla',
     :fog_public => true,
     :fog_host => 'http://blablabla.rackcdn.com'
})
```

This allows you to upload to Rackspace in production mode. You don't need to change the model, and would call your `paperclip` objects like this:

```
@model.image.url #-> yields rackspace URL
```

If you need more help / clarity, please let me know. I have just used your Rackspace code & moved from an initializer to your config files